# Regexp parse type-3 grammar

Tags: regex, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, chomsky-hierarchy

Reading [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) ...
... I know regexp can't parse type-2 grammars (context-free grammars), and also type-1 and type-0.
Can regular expressions parse/catch ALL type-3 grammars ([regular grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided they support alternation, concatenation, and the Kleene star. This is the case for regexes of the PCRE (Perl/Java/JavaScript/PHP/...) type: alternation is implemented by `((...)|(...))`, concatenation by `(...)(...)`, and the Kleene star by `(...)*`. (There are a few other details — in most of these languages you need to use something like `\A` and `\z` to indicate "start-of-string" and "end-of-string", which in a regular grammar is taken for granted — but that's the idea.)

But not everything called a "regular expression" in a programming context necessarily has all of the above; for example, [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) supports only a very limited form of alternation, where all "branches" of the alternation consist of a single character (e.g., whereas PCREs has both `(a|b|c)` and the special-case-equivalent `[abc]`, POSIX BREs only have `[abc]`, so can't express something like `(ab|c)`).